# Calling a superclass constructor without a String?

Tags: java, superclass

I'm currently trying to call the constructor of the superclass Album, with `super();` but it won't work. This problem seems to stem from the fact that I'm trying to call it with an object of type Artist instead of a String, but even when I use a String, it still doesn't work. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong - and whether there's a better way to make the call:

```
public class StudioAlbum extends Album {

    private Artist artist;

    public StudioAlbum(String name, Artist artist) {
        super(artist);
        this.name = name;
        this.artist = artist;
        albumType = "Studio";
    }

    public void setArtist(Artist artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }
}
```

In case this is useful, the Album class looks like this (without methods):

```
public class Album {

    protected String name;
    private ArrayList<Track> trackList;
    private int length; 
    private int fileSize;
    private double averageRating;
    protected String albumType;

    public Album(String name){
        this.name = name;
        trackList = new ArrayList<Track>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get when you're using a `String` ?

Comment: The `Album` constructor expects you to give it the name of the album.  So you need to give it the name of the album.  That applies when you call `super`, just as when you say `new Album`.  You need to say `super(name)`.

Comment: Did you pass the wrong parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The class `Album` does not have a parameterless constructor. Look here for an explanation: [Changing public data to private data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762641/changing-public-data-to-private-data-in-java/26762727#26762727)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be calling `super(name)`.  The superclass constructor takes a `String` for the name of the album, and your subclass does the same but also takes an `Artist`.

> but even when I use a String, it still doesn't work

It should.  If it doesn't then you have some bad syntax or something.

Comment: When I do, it pulls up this method: `public String getArtist() { return artist; }` 

and says 'incompatible types' because of artist. Does that clarify anything?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting Strings and Artists mixed up. Here's the corrected code first:

```
public class StudioAlbum extends Album {

    private Artist artist;

    public StudioAlbum(String name, Artist artist) {
        super(name);
        this.name = name;
        this.artist = artist;
        albumType = "Studio";
    }

    public void setArtist(Artist artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public Artist getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }
}

public class Album {

    protected String name;
    private ArrayList<Track> trackList;
    private int length; 
    private int fileSize;
    private double averageRating;
    protected String albumType;

    public Album(String name){
        this.name = name;
        trackList = new ArrayList<Track>();
    }
}
```

There are classes Artist and Track needed as well.

The superclass, Album expects a String in its constructor. StudioAlbum takes a String (name) and an Artist (artist). The only way to make this work reworking things (which might be appropriate) is to call super() with name, the String. If you want to superclass to take the Artist, you need to change the class Album to use the class Artist not a String to store name.

Comment: Tip on issues like this. I just copied your code in an IDE (Eclipse is what I had handy), and generated mockup (empty) classes for what was missing (Artist and Track). Then just the syntax highlight and type-checker point out the errors and offered reasonable corrections before I even tried compiling it. Best not to rely too heavily on IDEs and tools, but sometimes, that just make things trivial.

Answer (score 0):

So, as already said, `Album` does not have a parameterless constructor, so you **can't** use `super();`.
Moreover, the second line of your `StudioAlbum`'s constructor (`this.name = name`) is useless because already done in the `Album`'s constructor.

Here is a more common way to do what you want:

```
public Album(String name, String albumType) {
   this.name = name;
   this.albumType = albumType;
   this.trackList = new ArrayList<>(); // diamond operator from java7
}

public StudioAlbum(String name, Artist artist){
   super(name, "Studio");
   this.artist = artist ;
}
```

With this, you can set `private` all the fields of `Album` (which is often the best practice).